# Detect Different Machine using Browser

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, browser

Some webapps like Facebook and gmail, detects the first time we try to login for the first time in one machine.

Assuming that a browser can't read machine name, and MAC ADDRESS. What kind of variables are they collection for doing this validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They check for cookies, which are stored by the browser on the client pc and sent to the servers. If there is no certain cookie present they assume it is the first time.

[image]

Image source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Comment: Hi Nick, but some banks are using the same method as extra security, and they shouldn't create cookies in users machines. Do you know any other way without cookies?

Comment: You could use multiple HTTP requests (maybe trough AJAX) and transmit any stored data that can be accessed with JavaScript, e.g. LocalStorage, WebSQL or IndexedDB. Also you can identify a Single Machine with a combination of all the transmitted data (resolution, browser etc.) See: https://panopticlick.eff.org/